# How to add Descriptive text to Items in radionbuttonList ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add a descriptive text to each item in my radionbuttonList, not that the description of the first item is different from the second one. I find this article, but it is not working for me. I am using .net Framework 4, and acccording to the article, it is supported. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist.render(v=vs.110).aspx
The code behind is vb.net

I want the description 'First element' to be under the item 'First',
 decrption 'second' to be under the item 'second'

```
     <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="myList">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">First</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">second</asp:ListItem>

  </asp:RadioButtonList>
  <p>
    First element 
    <br/>
    second element
  </p>
```

Comment: You have forgotten to show your code. It's not even clear how you are adding the items. Are you using a `DataSource` or are you addding the programmatically? Note that there is a `Items` property and every `ListItem` has a `Value` and `Text` property.

Comment: <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="myList">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">First</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">second</asp:ListItem>

      </asp:RadioButtonList>
      <p>
        First element 
        <br/>
        second element
      </p> I want the description 'First element' to be under the item 'First', decrption 'second' to be under the item 'second'

Comment: @user3393370 Don't put code in comment. Update your question